# (Android / Java / SQLite) Why my database is empty?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have the following class:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "days.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "days";
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "blob";
    private Context context;


    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_1 + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_2 + " BLOB)");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

And I have this in my MainActivity that starts when the app starts:

```
...
Database db;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);
        db = new Database(this);
```

}

But when I save the database from the device through the Device File Explorer, the days.db does not have anything. It is there, I can save it but in SQLite DB Browser I have 0 tables. May I ask you why?

[SQLite DB Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9azYr.jpg)

Comment: Looks to me like you have an infinite loop. You call `onCreate()` from `onCreate()`.

Comment: Hi, @Laklam, You should use the `SQLHelper()`, not `this`. try again, please.
`SQLHelper  helper = new SQLHelper(context); db=helper.getWritableDatabase();`